TRPC: What object is passed to the function passed to a procedure?
I'm having a hard time understanding from trpc's official docs exactly how to get the various properties of a Request object that comes to my API into the procedures I define in a trpc router.
The official trpc docs are full of examples of procedures defined like this:
getUserById: t.procedure.input(z.string()).query((opts) => {
    return users[opts.input]; // input type is string
  })

From this, I can tell that query takes a function as an argument.  And I'm assuming that the argument to that function is either an object that represents an entire http request (such as the Request object), or an object representing some subset of the properties of an http request.
What I can't find in the trpc docs (and I'm hoping someone will tell me) is exactly what type of object is getting passed to that function.  I have tried looking for the API definition of (for instance) the query method, but haven't found anything that looks like it.
So...What exactly is the type of the parameter of the function that gets passed to query?
Thanks!
